# Unable to run flutter project on IOS with firestore

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am unable to run flutter project on IOS simulator. I have integrated Cloud Firestore for Firebase with the project. The project is running perfectly on Android Device, but couldnt able to run it on IOS Simulator.

I would be thankful if any one can help me out solve this issue.

When I run pod install command I got the following error Please check.

```html
Muhammads-MacBook-Pro:ios bhatti$ pod install Analyzing dependencies [!] CDN: trunk Repo update failed - 44 error(s): CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/3.2.0/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/3.2.1/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/3.3.0/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/3.3.1/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/3.4.2/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/3.4.3/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/3.4.4/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/3.5.1/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/3.6.0/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/3.7.0/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/3.8.0/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/3.9.0/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/4.0.0/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/4.0.1/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/4.0.2/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/4.0.3/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/4.0.4/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/4.0.5/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/4.0.9/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/4.1.0/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/4.2.0/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/5.0.0/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/5.0.1/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/5.1.0/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/5.1.1/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/5.1.2/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/5.1.4/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/5.2.0/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/5.3.0/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/5.4.0/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/5.5.0/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/5.6.0/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/5.7.0/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/5.8.0/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/5.8.1/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/6.0.0/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/6.0.1/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/6.0.2/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/6.0.3/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/6.0.4/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/6.1.0/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/6.1.1/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/6.1.2/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/6.1.3/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,
error: Failed to open TCP connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known)
```

Error

```html
*** First throw call stack:
(
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23baa1ee __exceptionPreprocess + 350
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff50864b20 objc_exception_throw + 48
 2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23baa02c +[NSException raise:format:] + 188
 3   Runner                              0x0000000103e82d7a +[FIRApp configure] + 138
 4   Runner                              0x0000000104397086 -[FLTCloudFirestorePlugin init] + 214
 5   Runner                              0x0000000104396f11 +[FLTCloudFirestorePlugin registerWithRegistrar:] + 289
 6   Runner                              0x0000000103e7e5c0 +[GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:] + 112
 7   Runner                        <…>

Error connecting to the service protocol: HttpException: , uri = http://127.0.0.1:62281/vg54TtZ_CH0=/ws
```

AppDelegate

```html
#include "AppDelegate.h"
#include "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  [GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:self];
  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

@end
```

Comment: can you show what error you got on the console?

Comment: and what the simulator does on start...

Comment: Have you copied the GoogleService-Info.plist file in Runner directory by using Xcode?

Comment: @DharmeshMansata thanks for your response. I am getting this error Error running pod install when I try to run the app.

Comment: @CanTaşpınar yes I have added it in /ios/Runner folder

Comment: Can you try flutter clean in your project directory? After that cd into ios directory and try pod update

Comment: try `pod install` from the terminal this would help.

Comment: @DharmeshMansata I have run pod install command from terminal and I got a lot of errors one of the error is this : CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/3.2.0/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json,

Comment: looks like an internet connection issue to me

Comment: try to clear cache, with `flutter clean` and make sure plist file have boolean type `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` set `NO`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be many reasons. kindly provide a screenshot of error or error message something more informative.

I recently added `cloud_firestore` and It took days to solve dependencies issues for ios.

Some common errors are:

1. Version Compatibility You need atleast `XCode version 10.1` for firestore.
2. Pod files are not installed.
   To solve this From terminal goto `yourproject/ios`
   directory and run the following command

> `pod install`

3. Make sure you performed this [Step](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup)

If you can provide more information or steps you did I can guide you further.

Comment: I am using xcode Version 11.1 and mac os catilina. I have added the error please check. Thanks

Comment: Ok, At what step you are ?
After adding `cloud_firestore:` in `pubsepc.yaml` file.
Run flutter `flutter pub get` 
Then run `pod install`

Comment: @tyb9900 After running pod install, above mentioned error gone. Now I am getting another error when app runs I think it get crashed, I have added the error in question please check

Comment: @EhsanBhatti Ok, I got `First throw call stack:` error too.
It sometimes due to `AppDelegate.m` file when we add `[FIRApp Configure]`
can you show your `AppDelegate.m` File ?

Comment: @tyb9900 I have added it in my question. Please check

Comment: @EhsanBhatti add `@import Firebase;` after `#include "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"` and add `[FIRApp Configure]` before `return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];` in your `AppDelegate.m`

Reference : https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#initialize-firebase

Comment: @tyb9900 Many Many Thanks for guiding me. I have resolve this when I put google json file from xcode. now its working and fetching data from firestore. Again Thakyou for guiding me